# Why is urlfetch throwing Download Errors when calling some Google services?

Tags: google-app-engine, ip-address, urlfetch

I've noticed that some Google services are blocking requests from App Engine servers, resulting in a urlfetch DownloadError. An example would be a feedproxy.google.com url (http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/blabbermouth/~3/cAk78LX4gJE/news.aspx, for example).

This occurs on all the apps I've tried it on, including app IDs I've never used for any kind of url fetching before. This behavior also **doesn't** occur on the local SDK. This leads me to believe that this is a result of using any GAE IP address when making the request.

The weird thing is that it results in the throwing of a DownloadError, instead of an error status_code in the successfully retrieved response. Using urlfetch or httplib locally works just fine, so this DownloadError I don't yet grok, or it's just a bug, in which case I'll file a ticket.

Comment: Someone mentioned (http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/98b38f1f5cdb592c) adding headers={ "Accept-Encoding" : "identity" }, but that didn't seem to help. Maybe you could try setting up a simple server to see what's the difference between the request headers sent by appspot vs. your local machine. Maybe there is some issue here similar to that accept-encoding header issue.

Comment: Nope, headers isn't the issue. I've tried the exact same fetch calls locally and on production, and the only difference AFAIK is the IP address being used.

Answer (score 1):

Without having a look at your code I will be guessing but since the URL that you are following is a going to redirect are you allowing redirects in your call? Note the `follow_redirects=True`

e.g. `urlfetch.fetch(url, payload=None, method=GET, headers={}, allow_truncated=False, follow_redirects=True, deadline=None)`

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html

Comment: Not setting follow_redirects just means that I should get back a response with a 301 or 302 status_code. An error being thrown implies something else entirely.